# How to set Java Xmx flag when running an application via Maven Spring Boot Plugin?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I am running an application using `mvn spring-boot:run`. I am trying to set the `Xmx` flag as described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/maven-plugin/examples/run-system-properties.html):

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Xmx512m"
```

but it does not seem to work. No matter what `Xmx` I set, `Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()` always gives me `2147483648` on a machine with 8GB RAM (which is the default = 1/4 of total RAM).

How can I fix this? I cannot hardcode any value in `pom.xml`. I am using version `3.1.4` of the plugin.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.4</version>
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. The problem was that I was also setting `jvmArguments` in `pom.xml` under the `configuration` section of the plugin and when you do this the `jvmArguments` specified on the command line have no effect.